# Mobility Radeon X1400 with Radeon HD 6570

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

My Lenovo ThinkPad T60 laptop has a Mobility Radeon X1400.  I have a [docking station with a PCIe](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-61232) port, where I have installed a [Radeon HD 6570](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102942).

Windows 7 (64-bit) reports both cards in the device manager.  I've installed the latest drivers.  If I boot up the laptop and then dock it while it is on ([as suggested by some other folks online](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T61-and-prior-T-series-ThinkPad/Thinkpad-T60-and-advanced-dock-with-PCIe-Video-Running-both/td-p/1047905)), the on-board card stays running and the 6570 is unable to start up.  The device manager reports this error:

> This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

If I boot while docked the on-board card only comes up in VGA mode with device manager reporting that the onboard X1400 "reported a problem", with the 6570 still showing code 31.

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

It seems that there is a driver conflict of sorts between the two cards.  Is there any way to resolve this conflict, or further narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this exact combination of GPUs, but I will say that many laptops have trouble with GPUs from the same vendor in an eGPU scenario like this.  I can vouch for having seen this issue on multiple Thinkpads.  It seems to be less of a driver problem and more of a firmware problem - Windows will give a complaint along these lines, but it's not really something that drivers will fix.

In light of this, I doubt there's any easy workaround to get that HD 6570 working, but an Nvidia card would probably work just fine.

It's also possible that it's an issue with the onboard memory of the card - I have seen certain laptops with firmware such that the BIOS can't properly allocate memory for an additional GPU beyond a certain amount (usually 256 or 512MB).  I can't say I've heard of the T60 doing this, but then I've never tried.  There's no workaround for this either short of using a different card.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  For what it's worth, I'm able to use the card if I configure it in the BIOS as the boot card (which disables the X1400).  It works great in this configuration, but to switch back to the onboard, I have to reboot and reinstall the drivers for the X1400.  It isn't until I reinstall those drivers that things work again... the more I think about it, the more I think some driver file may be shared with each driver requiring a different version of it.  I've got an Nvidia card, but it's about 2mm too big to fit.  I guess I'll break out the Dremel.

Comment: @Brad - Yeah, that behavior (where if it's primary the other card is disabled) is exactly what I'd expect from this kind of behavior.  No promises, but I'd expect the Nvidia card to work.  (Can you possible try installing it in whatever adapter you have outside its chassis before you go modding it?)

Comment: Somewhere around here I have a PCIe riser card on a short cable... but I think that cutting into the docking station is going to be easier than finding it.  :-D